# Postgresql - query problem

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a variable which is in this format 2011-05-13.
I want to make a query that adds one day to this variable and searches for days like this in the database.

I made this query but it doesnt work.

```
select phone from employee where date like (select date '2011-05-13' + 1) %
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What type is the `"date"` field?  What does it mean that the query "doesn't work?"  Does it fail with a *syntax error*, because you meant to quote and concatenate that bare '%'?  Does it fail with *operator does not exist error* because there's no overloaded LIKE operator that accepts a timestamp field and a string, and your query above isn't precisely what you're executing?

Answer (score 5):

You need an INTERVAL:

```
SELECT phone FROM employee WHERE datefield = (date '2011-05-13' + INTERVAL '1 DAY') ;
```

Edit: Don't use LIKE when you're working with dates, there is no LIKE for a date.

Comment: My date row is like this 2011-05-13 22:13:09.969 so i need % symbol to match 2011-05-13. I dont know how to do this. 

Adding 1 day to 2011-05-13 works for me with this query select date '2011-05-13' + 1.

Comment: @tipotas: use between "where date between '2011-05-13' and '2011-05-14'" will get all the values on 5-13 as it will treat them as midnight to midnight.

Comment: Just cast your TIMESTAMP to a DATE: CAST(field AS DATE) = '2011-05-13'

Comment: Seems like (according to OP) the column in question is of type text. I kinda doubt that but who knows. @tipotas: what type is the "date" column mentioned in your example query?

Comment: @Milen A. Radev: That would be a bug, he should fix that.

Comment: @invertedSpear - that BETWEEN predicate will incorrectly match records from the first second of the upper boundary day ('2011-05-14 00:00:00').

Comment: Note that if you need to truncate a timestamp,use date_trunc.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT phone FROM employee WHERE to_char(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')::timestamp = ('2011-05-13'::timestamp + '1 day'::interval)
```

Comment: YOu could also use date_trunc('day', date) instead of to_char().

Comment: Just CAST it to a DATE and you're fine. You don't need a string function to_char() to extract just the date part.

Comment: use of to_char() in this manner probably makes it impossible to use an index.